# how to omit default message in debug module

Tags: debugging, module, ansible

```yaml
  - name:
    debug: 
    with_items: "{{ result.stdout }}"
```

```
TASK [pvc_precheck : check_rpm_versionlock warning message] ********************
skipping: [ip]
 {
    "msg": "Hello world!"
}
```

Somehow came across this test case. Here, when I run this code in Ansible got output  but default message is also printing `"Hello world!"`
How can I omit this default message, I don't want any custom message as well, just executing it is enough.

Comment: What is the use-case? Why are you running debug when you don't want to see anything?

Comment: @VladimirBotka
 -  name: output of command
    debug:
    with_items: "{{ result.stdout }}"

here result is getting printed as i mentiones result.stdout but however the default message is also getting printed in output.so i just want to eliminate default msg

Comment: Don't put code into the comment. [edit] your question and make it [mre].

Comment: @VladimirBotka This is the scenario ..where  ``` Hello world ! ``` is printing as default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: **"*Don't want any custom message as well. Just execution is enough.*"**

A: If 'just execution is enough' use [meta: noop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html#ansible-builtin-meta-execute-ansible-actions) e.g. the task below just silently does nothing

```yaml
    - meta: noop
```

---

Notes

**1. Module debug doesn't require arguments**

It's not possible to make [debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html) display nothing. It wouldn't make sense. Why do you want to run debug when you don't want to see anything? No parameter is mandatory. `msg` defaults to `"Hello world!"` and `var` defaults to `0` e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: Hello world!
```

---

**2. Condition**

Use a condition if you want to skip `debug` (eliminate message) e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
      when: debug_enable|default(false)|bool
```

---

**3. Undefined variable**

If the variable might be undefined it's possible to either skip the task e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
      when: result.stdout is defined
```

, or display a default value e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.stdout|default('NOT DEFINED') }}"
```